# How should I best approach a project which involves merging separate apps together?

Tags: mobile-application, user-centered-design, app

I need to merge 3 separate apps for a project at work. One app is for smart homes devices, one is for smart condo management (booking facilities, etc.) and one is for smart towns.

Does anyone know any good resources about how to approach merging different apps into a single app from a UX perspective?

Comment: Welcome to UX StackExchange. It sounds like you have a large and possibly intimidating project. There are likely case studies that you can find by searching, but how might we help you with a specific problem around this? What is the one problem you're trying to solve for your users, and what approaches have you tried so far?